# How to load powershell profile from cygwin bash?

Tags: bash, cygwin, powershell

So in cygwin bash I am able to type "powershell" to bring me into a powershell prompt but it won't load my powershell profile.ps1 due to not being able to execute scripts, but I can't set the execution policy in this prompt...

So I tried running the default powershell prompt (as administrator) and was able to set the execution policy to remote signed, but it doesn't affect the powershell within bash

what am I missing?

[image: Bash Powershell]
[image: Powershell As Administrator]

Answer (score 1):

You could run this from your bash shell:

```
 powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

**EDIT**

For me this works without the dash before cmdlet so:

> powershell ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass
```